# data-config.xml lost when solrconfig.xml edited

Tags: solr, solr4

With solr set up for multicore (which may or may not be relevant), I had a working test system. `solrconfig.xml` lived in `/solr-4.4.0/example/multicore/expertise/conf` and looked essentially like the example solrconfig file for multicore, except for the following lines:

```
<dataDir>/data/website_data/solr_cores/expertise</dataDir>

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">/data/website_data/solr_cores/expertise/data-config.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Since I wanted a language-aware solr, I updated solrconfig.xml with some select handlers (previously `handleSelect` had been `true`) and a new `updateRequestProcessorChain`. The changes to solrconf.xml look like this:

```
<lib dir="${user.dir}/../contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/" /><!-- relative to solrs 'example' directory -->
<lib dir="${user.dir}/../contrib/analysis-extras/lib/" />
<lib dir="${user.dir}/../dist/" regex="solr-langid-.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${user.dir}/../contrib/langid/lib/" />    

<!-- required for language detection of input records -->
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="languages">
    <processor class="solr.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="langid.fl">focus, expertise, platforms, partners, participation, additional</str>
            <str name="langid.whitelist">en,fr</str>
            <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>
            <str name="langid.langField">detectedlang</str>
            <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>
            <bool name="langid.map.keepOrig">false</bool>
        </lst>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>

<!-- uses language-detecting update.chain -->
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="update.chain">languages</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>

<requestDispatcher handleSelect="false"> <!-- ORIGINALLY FALSE -->
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="false" multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048" formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048" />
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
</requestDispatcher>

<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">focus^2, expertise^2, platforms, partners, participation, additional</str><!-- default query looks in these fields, with these boosts -->
        <str name="f.focus.qf">focus_en focus_fr</str><!-- field alias 'focus' means en AND fr versions of focus -->
        <str name="f.expertise.qf">expertise_en expertise_fr</str>
        <str name="f.platforms.qf">platforms_en platforms_fr</str>
        <str name="f.partners.qf">partners_en partners_fr</str>
        <str name="f.participation.qf">participation_en participation_fr</str>
        <str name="f.additional.qf">additional_en additional_fr</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/selectEN" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">focus^2, expertise^2, platforms, partners, participation, additional</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="fq">detectedlang:en</str>
        <str name="f.focus.qf">focus_en</str>
        <str name="f.expertise.qf">expertise_en</str>
        <str name="f.platforms.qf">platforms_en</str>
        <str name="f.partners.qf">partners_en</str>
        <str name="f.participation.qf">participation_en</str>
        <str name="f.additional.qf">additional_en</str>
        <str name="uf">* -focus_* -expertise_* -platforms_* -partners_* -participation_* -additional_*</str><!-- direct query any field except language-defined ones -->
        <str name="fl">*,focus:focus_en, expertise:expertise_en, platforms:platforms_en, partners:partners_en,
            participation:participation_en, additional:additional_en</str><!-- return lang-defined field when asked for generic field -->
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
<requestHandler name="/selectFR" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">focus^2, expertise^2, platforms, partners, participation, additional</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="invariants">
        <str name="fq">detectedlang:fr</str>
        <str name="f.focus.qf">focus_fr</str>
        <str name="f.expertise.qf">expertise_fr</str>
        <str name="f.platforms.qf">platforms_fr</str>
        <str name="f.partners.qf">partners_fr</str>
        <str name="f.participation.qf">participation_fr</str>
        <str name="f.additional.qf">additional_fr</str>
        <str name="uf">* -focus_* -expertise_* -platforms_* -partners_* -participation_* -additional_*</str><!-- direct query any field except language-defined ones -->
        <str name="fl">*,focus:focus_fr, expertise:expertise_fr, platforms:platforms_fr, partners:partners_fr,
            participation:participation_fr, additional:additional_fr</str><!-- return lang-defined field when asked for generic field -->
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Now I get the error: 
`Can't find resource '/data-config.xml' in classpath or 'multicore/expertise/conf/', cwd=/solr-4.4.0/example</str>`

The datapath didn't change. The data-config.xml file exists where it is supposed to be and its permissions are correct. Why can my original solrconf.xml find data-config.xml and my new one can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the order of statements in solrconfig.xml can make a difference. In this case, any `<lib/>` declarations must come after one (or possibly all) of these: `<luceneMatchVersion/>`, `<directoryFactory/ >`, `<dataDir>`, `<schemaFactory/>` and `<updateHandler/>`.

Initially, my `<lib>` lines were immediately after the opening `<config>` tag. This happens to be where they are put in the [example](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/blob/master/published/languages/conf/solrconfig.xml) that I was working from. So perhaps Java was just out of sorts and there was no problem with my solrconfig.xml.

I hope this helps someone else.